# fireEvent.change() does not input value

Tags: reactjs, testing-library

I have a very simple form which has 1 input and currently doing testing on it. However, I can unable to fireEvent.change() to add the input.

Main Code

```
function Submission(){
    // I understand that I can just simply do [name, setName] but in the future there will be more input, this is just for testing
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        name: ''
    })
    
    const updateForm = (e) => {setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.id]: e.target.value })};

    return (
        <div>
            <TextField id="name" type='string' label="Name" value={formData.name} onChange={(e)=>updateForm(e)} required/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Test Block

```
it('Can put enter value into the input', () => {
    const {getByLabelText} = render(<Submission/>);
    const input = getByLabelText(/name/i);
    fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: 'name' }});
    expect(input).toBe('name');
  });
```

Error

```
  ● Submission › Can put enter value into the input

    expect(received).toContain(expected) // indexOf

    Expected value:  "name"
    Received object: <input aria-invalid="false" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input" id="name" required="" type="string" value="" />

      72 |     const input = getByLabelText(/name/i);
      73 |     fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: 'name' }});
    > 74 |     expect(input).toContain('name');
         |                   ^
      75 |   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved by setting
`const input = getByLabelText(/name/i); as HTMLInputElement;`

Comment: the 'HTMLInputElement' is only required for Typescript